# How to send a client certificate from a .NET 5 site to an OwinRequest in a .NET 4.7.2 site via REST communication?

Tags: .net, owin, .net-4.7.2

I'm trying to send a client certificate from a .NET 5 app using REST communication to a FW 4.7.2 app

From .NET 5 application, I use HttpClientHandler adding client certificate from my storage of certificates. This has to be received in FW 4.7.2 app with OwinRequest.

We use HttpClient and add HttpClientHandler with certificate.

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
// Add valid client certificate to handler
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
handler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(GetClientCertificate(x509AuthSettings));
// Create new HTTP Client using handler
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xmlMessage);
LoggingHelper.WriteLogsForAllLoggers($"requestUri: {requestUri}", PriorityEnum.Info, new string[] { LoggingConstants.DELIVER_MESSAGE_LOGGER });
// Create POST request to serverUri endpoint
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    RequestUri = new Uri(requestUri),
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};

// Send request and wait for the response
LoggingHelper.WriteLogsForAllLoggers($"Send POST request to {requestUri}. Timeout is set to {client.Timeout}. Waiting for response...", PriorityEnum.Info, new string[] { LoggingConstants.DELIVER_MESSAGE_LOGGER });

var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

My problem is when received the Request, the certificate emitted from client is not present. I'm trying to find in the context through the key ssl.ClientCertificate.

```cs
IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment = Request.Environment;

var certLoader = Context.Get<Func<Task>>("ssl.LoadClientCertAsync");
if (certLoader != null)
{
    await certLoader();
}

X509Certificate2 clientCert = Context.Get<X509Certificate2>("ssl.ClientCertificate");
```

Comment: Unfortunately [so] is an English only site although there is a Spanish language version at [es.so]

Answer (score 0):

For IIS change the site's SSL Settings to [accept client certificates](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ssl-certificate-based-authentication-in-web-api-project/):

[image: IIS SSL Settings page]

For IISExpress, edit your `.vs/<SOLUTION_NAME>/config/applicationhost.config` and [set this attribute to `true`](https://improveandrepeat.com/2017/07/how-to-configure-iis-express-to-accept-ssl-client-certificates/):

```
<iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true">
</iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
```

I didn't have to do anything with the "ssl.LoadClientCertAsync", or call the `await certLoader();`. When it came to my `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.ValidateClientAuthentication` method, the context was already populated with the certificate in the OWIN environment's "ssl.ClientCertificate".